# Python Simple if

Tags: python, if-statement, printing, while-loop

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
a = 0
if a == 5:
    print"Congrats you hit five!"

while a <10:
    a = a + 1
    print a
    time.sleep(.5)
```

So my program counts to ten no problem.. But it never display the text when a == 5.
Any ideas? This is my first attempts at python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` code should be *inside* your `while` loop:

```
import time
a = 0

while a < 10:
    a = a + 1
    print a
    if a == 5:
        print"Congrats you hit five!"
    time.sleep(.5)

[OUTPUT]
1
2
3
4
5
Congrats you hit five!
6
7
8
9
10
```